Pasting flipped over X-axis

When I paste flipped over the x axis in animate/pose mode, it pastes but the wrong direction.


Hello, maybe your bones are not correctly oriented, hard to say, could you please share your file?

I just got a pre-rigged model from someone in a developing discord so I should be fine, but thanks
